# I need advice for which database system to use

Tags: database-design, information-schema, application-design

I have to create a database from scratch for the first time and I am not sure which system I should try. I will have specific IP addresses, IP ranges, domain names, host names which will be the key for a given customer. I want my database to be filterable by the customer's key. Each key will have a variety of different forms of data associated with it. For example, a key may have a list of open ports, any identified services, etc. Sometimes a key will be a website, and the data associated with it may be cookie names, URLs, and parameters. If I later find out that a customer's parameter is vulnerable, I want to be able to search through all of the customer's for that vulnerability.

What database system should I try using? What would be the most flexible and efficient? I don't want to try a database that isn't for my scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a shopping list question, which is not applicable on this site.

---

> Each key will have a variety of different forms of data associated with it.

Your data is pretty relational sounding. Any modern relational database management system (RDBMS) would be fine (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle SQL, MySQL, MariaDB, etc). They're all equally performant, when your database is architected properly. Stick to a modern one because there'll be better documentation, help, and communities around them.

> I want to be able to search through all of the customer's for that vulnerability.

This is the only caveat. It depends on the kind of searching you're going to want to be commonly doing, which will also depend on how you architect your database.

For example, if you store all of the customer's parameters as a single string in the database, then you'll likely need to use a Full Text Search type of feature with a RDBMS, or spend a little effort architecting additional implementations to support searching such as trigram indexes, should you need to do a *contains* type of searching. You may find the database system ElasticSearch more efficient and easier to work with in that case instead.

Alternatively, if you normalized your data, and stored each parameter in its own row, such that you don't need to do *contains* type of searching, then traditional indexing will be sufficient for searching in an RDBMS. Most things with data and performance come down to how you architect your database, not the software system you use as your database system to actually store the data.

Aside from all of that, you definitely don't need a traditional NoSQL or Graph database solution based on what you've described. So don't get sucked in trying to shoehorn your data and goals into one of those systems, like others have.